# scrapy doesn't seem to optimize on depth_limit

Tags: limit, scrapy, depth

I am new to scrapy and it seems this problem has not been asked.

The question is, I just want to get a shallow crawl of a large site(around 500 links), so I set `depth_limit=1` (maybe later will extend to 2 or 3), and also require the spider to filter all duplicate response.

However, after reading the log, I find that even when `depth_limit=1`, the crawler still checks a lot of outlinks of the front page (around 100000) and all returned `depth > 1`, which is a waste of time as all links on the front page are with depth 1, then the links generated will definitely with depth 2 or higher. I think There is no reason to check the outlinks of links with depth 1 to find outlinks with depth equal to 1.

So how do I write my settings to implement my own logic or optimize the spider?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. Scrapy does extra work over here.

Depth limit ( or depth filter) is implemented as a middleware at the end of the pipeline. So after the whole cycle ( scrape the page, generate the item, generate the request ) it filters the requests.

I can outline a solution as,

If you are using BaseSpider then you can use request.meta to store the depth and increment it for the request generated. As you are the one who generates requests in the parse callback effectively you will not generate the request when the depth is reached.

If you are using crawl spider then you have to override "_requests_to_follow" of the base CrawlSpider. Still you will be propagating depth. Everything will be same in the _request_to_follow except when the depth is reached you will not extract and generate request.

Hope it helps.